# Responsive Images in Footer

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage, fluid-images

I am having a problem with the spacing of an image in Safari / Firefox. I am working on a mobile version of a site and all the images are using percentage based widths so they are responsive.

For some reason in Safari / Firefox there is spacing issues on the Contact Bar (Footer). It works perfectly in chrome but there is black space on the right of the "Map" image in Safari and black space on the left of the "Map" image in Firefox.

There are 7 images spanning the width of the Footer Container and their widths add to 100% ( 3 images are 10%, 3 x 20%, 1 x 30%)

You can view it here

www.conchandmedia.com/new_mobile/index3.html

Max Widths are not set so please just resize your browser to the width that a phone would be.

Any suggestions on what is causing this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Viewing it on nexus 4 in chrome looks perfectly fine, 6 across and 1 below the first 3, no additional black spaces. Just to let you know.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate you checking it.....I had a few people tell me the same for android but IOS is not working and this is a major requirement.